# Why Elastic beanstalk restore to old version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

why Elastic beanstalk restore to old version in AWS.

i try to deploy simple leraval project to aws.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Beanstalk is a service that makes it easy to deploy, run, and scale web applications and services on the **Amazon Web Services (AWS)** platform. When you deploy your application to Elastic Beanstalk, it creates an environment for your application and manages the details of the infrastructure and application components for you.

In some cases, Elastic Beanstalk may automatically restore your application to a previous version if it detects that the new version you are deploying is not working correctly. This can happen if the new version is not compatible with the environment or if it is causing errors. Restoring to a previous version can help prevent downtime or other issues with your application.

*It is important to carefully test your application **before deploying it to Elastic Beanstalk, to ensure that it is compatible with the environment and will run smoothly.** This can help prevent issues like an automatic restoration to a previous version*